# Error! MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server - after connect to another wifi network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, wifi

I created an entire, working application with backend in Node.js and Mongodb (Mean stack). Everything is fine, but when I connect to another wifi network there is an error. Please help me.
If I have to send more code from the app, write it.

```
Error! MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [eventsdb-shard-00-00-ydx5k.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to eventsdb-shard-00-00-ydx5k.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> 
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at net.js:659:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:481:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
```

...\App\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:372:9 :

```
function closeHandler(conn) {
  return function(hadError) {
    if (connectionAccounting) deleteConnection(conn.id);

    if (conn.logger.isDebug()) {
      conn.logger.debug(`connection ${conn.id} with for [${conn.address}] closed`);
    }

    if (!hadError) {
      conn.emit(
        'close',
        new MongoNetworkError(`connection ${conn.id} to ${conn.address} closed`), // <------ 372
        conn
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you ping `eventsdb-shard-00-00-ydx5k.mongodb.net` from the "wi-fi network"?

Comment: I did it and It ping. What else can I do?

Ping statistics for 63.32.165.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 79ms, Maximum = 2070ms, Average = 582ms

Comment: If you use something like [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) from that wifi network, does it work?

Comment: I don't use MongoDB Compas, but I connect with my app by connection string from MingoDB. I have already solved my problem, I wrote the solution in answer below. But thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. On the Mongodb website, where I have a database, I entered "Network Access" -> "Add IP Address", I added my new ip address and there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the a new ip adress to the ip list in mondodb atlas project
mongodb atlas=>click on the project=>Network Access(you probably gonna find it on left bar)=>add IP adress=>(probably gonna see a button to add your current ip adress)
if adding you current ip adress not working add this ip adress 0.0.0.0/0 it's gonna let you you cannect to the server from any ip adress(or any pc)

Comment: Does this add anything to Weronika's 2020 self answer?